# Anonymous class variables

Tags: java

I was experimenting with anonymous classes today. When I do `System.out.println(super.x);`, it prints 12, and when I use `System.out.println(x);` it prints 4. I thought `super.x` would print 4 and was wondering if someone could please explain to me why this is?

```
public class AnonClass {

    private int x = 1;

    public AnonClass(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnonClass test = new AnonClass(4);
        test.testMethod();
    }

    public void testMethod() {

        AnonClass anon = new AnonClass(12) {
            {
                System.out.println(super.x); //Prints 12
                System.out.println(x); //prints 4
            }
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: I thought `super` was only used with inheritance. I guess not.

Comment: @Gendarme why do you guess that? Anonymous classes inherit from the class they extend.

Comment: @AndyTurner Well, I guess my knowledge in Java is too... shallow. This whole thing is beyond me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you define an anonymous class like this inside `class AnonClass`:

```
AnonClass anon =
    new AnonClass(12) {
      {
        System.out.println(super.x); //Prints 12
        System.out.println(x); //prints 4
      }
    };
```

the compiler will create a class something like this:

```
class AnonClass$1 extends AnonClass {
  final AnonClass enclosed;

  AnonClass$1(AnonClass enclosed, int x) {
    super(x);
    System.out.println(super.x);
    System.out.println(enclosed.x);
    this.enclosed = enclosed;
  }
}
```

and then invoke it like:

```
AnonClass anon = new AnonClass$1(this, 12);
```

Note that the invocation of the superconstructor (`super(x);`) happens before the contents of the instance initializer (the `System.out.println` lines).

As such, the field `AnonClass.x` is initialized to 12 by the superconstructor, and then its value is printed as `12` via `System.out.println(super.x);`.

Then, `System.out.println(x)` is actually referencing the `x` in the enclosing instance of `AnonClass`, whose value is 4.

The reason it doesn't print `12` again is that `x` is `private`; and as it says in [JLS Sec 8.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2):

> Members of a class that are declared private are not inherited by subclasses of that class.

So there is no `AnonClass$1.x` to print; the only identifier in scope called `x` is `AnonClass.x`.

Comment: Which part of the java specification says that an unqualified identifier in an anonymous class resolves to the enclosing class and not the anonymous super class? I would have expected an "ambiguous" compilation error.

Comment: This is indeed an interesting question -- and one more reason to not use double brace initialization. A reference to the JLS regarding variable resolution in the instance initializer would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is a hint to answer my question, I guess: If you remove `private` from field `x`, both `super.x` and `x` refers to the super instance. Only when `x` is `private` will the unqualified `x` refer to the enclosing instance.

Comment: That is interesting, it seems to add a level of encapsulation when made private and allowed to share when public.

Answer (score 1):

You have two classes here: regular class `AnonClass` and anonymous class `AnonClass$1` extending `AnonClass`

Both these classes have `x` field

You also have two objects: one of type `AnonClass` instantiated inside `main` method with `x = 4` and second one of type `AnonClass$1` instantiated inside `testMethod()` with `x = 12`

When you're printing the value of `super.x` you are accessing the `x` field of second object; but the value of `x` belongs to the first object cause you class is not `static` and contains an implicit reference to instance of outer class

Reference: [Nested Classes in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)